# Use table data from different sql server in a .Net application

Tags: .net, sql-server, linked-server

I need to run stored procedures that make us of tables from a different sql server. The "Linked Server" or distributed transaction feature has been disabled on one of the servers; Therefore the tables cannot be joined from within the sproc. One server tables are to be updated and other server data is read only.

Because I am working on a ASP.Net Web application project, I was hoping if I can leverage it to solve this problem. The best solution I can think of is to read the table rows from one server as XML and supply it as an XML param to the sproc in other server database so that it can be converted back to a table and used. Do you have better ideas of doing it?

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you use XML? Just read data out from sql server instance 1, and do inserts into a table in sql server instance 2.

Comment: @RichardDesLonde how do you pass on a table to a storedprocedure?

Comment: Why are you intent on re-creating the table just to perform the updates?

Comment: @Aamir you don't pass a table to the stored procedure. You just use your .net ability to insert records into a table in the second database, then you can do what ever you want with it in SQL.

Comment: @RichardDesLonde , as per your advice, I think I have create proxy tables in the target server database. These tables will represent the read only/remote server tables. I will be using a SqlBulkCopy object to fill in these proxy tables first before using them as local tables in my sproc. Sounds like a good plan. Don't know which solution will be costlier, this one or the xml one, but this one sure sounds straight forward. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake. I completely spaced on the part where you state that you are not able to link to remote. I think the XML option is a better option in that case.Pass the XML data(after applying necessary filters to make the record as small as possible), and then parse the information in your second db's stored procedure as XML

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175160.aspx